# Spark 2.x - Shuffle on "small" data crashes "big" executors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My (Py)Spark 2.1.1 app consists in two executors with 5 cores and 30G heap (`spark.executor.memory`) each. I have 3.2Gb of data persisted in memory (deserialized) spread on a dozen partitions and shared between my two executors (1.9Gb + 1.3Gb). I then want to repartition this data by calling `repartition('myCol')` on my persisted dataframe with `myCol` having only three keys with a 60-20-20 distribution. I then want to write the repartitionned data in (3) .parquet files. As expected, this transformation triggers a full shuffle of the data :

- First question : In the Spark UI, Shuffle Write amounts to 5.9Gb. Why is this amount much higher than the size of the persisted data ? Is it the format Spark uses to write shuffle files on disk (text strings?) ? Replication ?
- Second question : My executors keep dying with error messages such as `org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle` or `ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 32.0 GB of 32 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.`. `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` is already set at `2g` but I must confess I don't really get how this parameter should help in that context. But the main question is : how shuffling 3Gb of data can OOM a 30Gb executor ?

I changed a few parameters from the understanding I have of Spark (with limited success obviously) : I set `spark.memory.fraction` to `0.9` and `spark.memory.storageFraction` to `0.0`.

Many thanks in advance for any help, this situation is so frustrating.

PS : Maybe once the issue is solved I can redesign my app with less memory per executor. It currently feels like a terrible waste of ressources to me.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  Running into the same problem.